# Bootstrapping servers with chef, and changing the SSH Port

Tags: ssh, chef

I have a full set of recipes that are working to bootstrap a server at Rackspace, it configures and installs everything as needed. Now, I want to change the default port SSH runs on. This is fairly easy to do, but the question is, how do I tell Knife to use 22 when bootstrapping, but the non standard port when doing everything else on registered nodes?

Comment: talked with the people in #chef on FreeNode and figured it out. When bootstrapping, I need to pass -c myboostrap.config where i have a setting saying knife[:ssh_port] = '22'

Comment: Add an answer and accept it, so others can learn from your experience.

Answer (score 0):

This has been in chef since version 0.9.16. You can configure the port by adding the following to your `.chef/knife.rb`.

```
knife[:ssh_port] = '22'
```

Change 22 to the port you want. You don't need to pass -c to the knife bootstrap command if your configuration is in `.chef/knife.rb` in the current directory.

[Ticket for this feature](http://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-1768).

[Commit for the change](https://github.com/opscode/chef/blob/74647525dc14868a4cc29a463934036a0a85db84/chef/lib/chef/knife/ssh.rb).

More information on configuring knife can be found on the Chef wiki:

- http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Knife
- http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Knife+Bootstrap

Comment: jtimberman, I saw the knife[:ssh_port] option, but the issue is I change the port to non 22, AFTER the bootstrap, so in knife.rb, I have the non standard port, but in the bootstrap it's still 22. Since the machine boots up at 22. 

Or maybe I'm not understanding what you're saying? (more than likely :)). 

Hope to see you or someone from your team at OSCON later this week.

Comment: I wouldn't bother with changing the port as setting SSH to run on an alternate port doesn't *really* increase security. An attacker of any sophistication (or one who wants to find out if you're running vulnerable SSH) is going to scan all the ports available.

Comment: I'm not changing ports for "security" like that, we're running proftpd with mod_sftp on port 22, and on a non standard port which would be needed for chef, and actual ssh only.